# Zurb/Foundation framework: how to align top-bar-section to the left instead to the right

Tags: javascript, css, css-frameworks

I am just learning zurb foundation css framework a bit and cannot figure out how to align the top-bar-section to the left? the default alignment seem to be at the center of the screen.

Is it something that is part of the framework or I will have to code by myself? you could see the top menu in action by going to http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/ and resize your browser or see the attached screenshot.
[image: top-bars-section aligned to the left on the zurb foundation homepage]

Comment: Could you please clarify? So you want to move the stacked bars that you highlighted to the left of the "Foundation" header text as displayed in your screenshot?

Comment: Nguyen. correct. that is what I want and I am not sure if there is any option I could set.

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same issue, but it seems like they just display the top bar in the large version with "top-bar hide-for-small". The other thing you see is a sidebar, which will be shown in the small version. If you want to know which classes are needed just use Firebug on their website and you should be fine.

Best regards,
Manuel